# How to make a web server using Erlang

Tags: mysql, web, erlang, backend

I'm new with Erlang

I try to make a web server with Erlang. How to do it with Erlang?
I was using this code to make a local:

```
-module(test). 
-export([start/0,service/3]). 

start() ->
   inets:start(httpd, [ 
      {modules, [ 
         mod_auth, 
         mod_esi, 
         mod_actions, 
         mod_cgi, 
         mod_dir,
         mod_get, 
         mod_head, 
         mod_log, 
         mod_disk_log 
      ]}, 

      {port,8082}, 
      {server_name,"helloworld"}, 
      {server_root,"C://xampp//tmp"}, 
      {document_root,"C://xampp//htdocs"}, 
      {erl_script_alias, {"/erl", [test]}}, 
      {error_log, "error.log"}, 
      {security_log, "security.log"}, 
      {transfer_log, "transfer.log"}, 

      {mime_types,[ 
         {"html","text/html"}, {"css","text/css"}, {"js","application/x-javascript"} ]} 
   ]). 

service(SessionID, _Env, _Input) -> mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, [ 
   "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 
   "<DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   <title>HTML1</title>
   <script
     src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js'
     integrity='sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE='
     crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
   <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
   <link href='css/test1.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
   <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
   </head>
      <html>
      <body>Ham oc cho!
         <div class='header'>
            <ul class='first'>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Tai khoan cua toi</a></li>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Trang thai don hang</a></li>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Danh sach ua thich</a></li>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Gio hang</a></li>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Dang nhap</a></li>
               <li class='col-md-4'><a href='#' >Dang ky</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </body>
      </html>" ]).
```

But I don't see any way to add a css-js file and don't know how to write a backend to this.

If you guy have some example or document pls share me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some useful Erlang tools like [**Cowboy**](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy), [**Mochiweb**](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb), [**Chicagoboss**](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss) and [**YAWS**](https://github.com/klacke/yaws) for working on web protocols.

Comment: Ty. I have a question: Can Erlang replace php?
I heard Erlang can support milion access and php just for a thousand access .Is that right?

Comment: Comparing Erlang (Toolbox) with PHP (Wrench) is wrong.

Comment: ty for answer my question. Is really help me

Comment: I think another good http server directly available with Erlang is [httpd](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpd.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might find it instructive to work through `sws`, my [Erlang simple web server](https://gist.github.com/vinoski/4996859). It shows how to handle connections, read HTTP requests from a socket, and send replies using Erlang's built-in socket support and HTTP support.

The web server works by accepting incoming connections and parsing incoming requests using Erlang's built-in support for HTTP request parsing — see line 29:

```
ok = inet:setopts(S, [{packet,http_bin}]),
```

The [`{packet, http_bin}` socket option](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2) tells Erlang to try to parse incoming socket data as HTTP. In the `serve/3` function at line 36, for flow control and backpressure purposes, we keep the socket in `{active, once}` mode, which also means `sws` receives incoming data from Erlang as messages — see lines 37-41:

```
ok = inet:setopts(S, [{active, once}]),
HttpMsg = receive
              {http, S, Msg} -> Msg;
              _ -> gen_tcp:close(S)
          end,
```

The `serve/3` function is recursive, receiving HTTP request data until we get a full request or an error. Once `serve/3` has a full request, it passes it to a handler function, which you're expected to provide when you call `sws:start/1,2`. The handler is expected to return a 3-tuple of HTTP status, HTTP reply headers, and HTTP reply body, where the headers or body can be empty depending on the return status.

For example, here's a simple "Hello, World!" application running in an Erlang shell:

```
1> c(sws).
{ok,sws}
2> Sws = spawn(sws, start, [fun(_,_) -> {200, [], <<"Hello, World!">>} end]).
<0.73.0>
```

Here, the `fun` passed as a handler always returns HTTP status 200, no reply headers, and a string binary for the reply body. Accessing the server via curl from a Unix shell shows the expected reply:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000
Hello, World!
```

If we pass `-v` to curl to show more details, we see:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
Hello, World!
```

First curl tries to connect over IPv6, which fails since `sws` doesn't support it (though it could), so it retries over IPv4, which succeeds. Curl then sends a `GET` request for the `/` resource. When curl sees the reply, it shows the 200 status code, and also note that it sees that the reply is HTTP 1.0 and thus correctly assumes the connection will close after the body is sent, so after receiving the reply it closes its side as well.

The handler function you supply takes two arguments: the client socket and a request object, which is a property list consisting of 2-tuples where the first tuple element is an atom identifying its associated data. For example, the handler can determine the invoked HTTP method by finding the `method` tuple in the `Request` argument using [`lists:keyfind/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3):

```
{method, Method} = lists:keyfind(method, 1, Request),
```

For our example above, `Method` would have the value of `'GET'` (an atom). Other properties of the request that can be discovered like this are:

- `uri` for the requested resource
- `version` for the client HTTP version
- `headers` for a list of the HTTP headers in the request

The handler function you supply can be as simple or complex as you wish. Note that if your handler fails and causes an exception, `sws` catches it and returns HTTP status code 500.

To stop the web server, back in the Erlang shell we send a `stop` message to the spawned `sws` process:

```
3> Sws ! stop.
stop
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Jul-2017::11:17:05 ===
Error in process <0.77.0> with exit value:
{{badmatch,{error,closed}},[{sws,accept,2,[{file,"sws.erl"},{line,28}]}]}
```

The error shown here, which can be ignored, is simply due to the fact that `sws` always assumes that `gen_tcp:accept/1` succeeds — see line 28:

```
{ok, S} = gen_tcp:accept(LS),
```

It would be easy enough to make this a `case` expression instead and handle error returns as well.

Note that `sws` is intended for demonstration and learning, and so it's intentionally not particularly efficient since it supports HTTP 1.0 only and handles only one request per connection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using http://phoenixframework.org/
It uses elixir which runs on the Erlang VM.